# How do I calculate time difference in Java?

Tags: java, time, java-time

So I am currently working on a project and I have a method which is suppose to help me calculate the working hours of employees based on a simple formula which is **work hours = logout - login - break.**

For some reason best known to my computer, the value of my break time gets reduced by 1 all the time. Can anyone please let me know why this is happening and how I can resolve it? Thanks

```
public String calculateHoursWorked() throws ParseException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your login time:");
    loginTime = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter your break duration:");
    breakTime = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter your logout time:");
    logoutTime = sc.nextLine();

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Date login = format.parse(loginTime);
    Date logout = format.parse(logoutTime);
    Date breakPeriod = format.parse(breakTime);

    //calculate the total number of hours worked in a day
    long totalHoursWorked = logout.getTime() - login.getTime() - breakPeriod.getTime();

    //get the breaktime in milliseconds to make sure we have the right value here
    long breakTimeinMilliseconds = breakPeriod.getTime();
    System.out.println("So our break time is ms is: "+ breakTimeinMilliseconds);
    String test = DurationFormatUtils.formatDuration(breakTimeinMilliseconds,"HH:mm");
    System.out.println("Your break time is: " + test);


    return DurationFormatUtils.formatDuration(totalHoursWorked, "HH:mm");

    //return String.valueOf(logout.getTime() - (login.getTime() + break_Period.getTime()));

}
```

This is the output I get on my console:

```
Please enter your login time:
02:00
Please enter your break duration:
**02:00**
Please enter your logout time:
10:00
So our break time is ms is: 3600000
**Your break time is: 01:00** (entered 02:00 above but I get 01:00 here)
Your working time is: 07:00 ***(This has to be 6)***
```

Comment: `Date` is a lie; it does not represent a date. It also doesn't represent a time. It represents epoch millis; an instant in time. Try to abuse this to do date math and things just break - timezones and such get in the way. These are the wrong datatypes. Date should never be used. The stuff in `java.time` is what you want. `Duration`, `Period`, `LocalTime`, `DateTimeFormatter`. You want those.

Comment: @rzwitserloot: Do you want to turn this into an answer, or shall I? It probably needs a slightly longer explanation to be understandable by novices ...

Comment: You don't need `Period`, but you definitely need `Duration` (for `breakDuration`) and `LocalTime` (for `loginTime` and `logoutTime`).  Also `DateTimeFormatter` to do the conversion to and from `String`.  Using `Date` was always going to be a problem, because it represents a moment on a particular day.  You might have been able to use it for `loginTime` and `logoutTime`, but certainly not for `breakDuration`.

Comment: @meriton go for it :)

Comment: Even for a point in time I strongly recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. As @DawoodibnKareem said, for your purpose use `LocalTime` and `Duration`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Parsing and formatting a `Duration` is not quite straightforward, but you can search and find how, it has been described a number of times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Javadoc of `Date` says:

> The class `Date` represents a specific instant in time, with millisecond precision.

and

> `public long getTime()`
>
> Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object.

Hm, so which Timezone is the SimpleDateFormatter using? It's Javadoc says:

> `public SimpleDateFormat(String pattern)`
>
> Constructs a SimpleDateFormat using the given pattern and the default date format symbols for the **default** FORMAT **locale**.

(emphasis mine)

The default locale is the default locale set in your computer's operating system.

So your program:

```
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Date breakPeriod = format.parse(breakTime);
    long breakTimeinMilliseconds = breakPeriod.getTime();
```

asks the computer to interpret the text as an instant in time using the default time zone of your computer. Your computer therefore interprets "02:00" as two hours after midnight, Central European Time. Then, you ask how long after midnight, GMT, that was. The computer knows that 02:00 CET is 01:00 GMT, so answers 3600000. That is, in using a class intended to represent instants in time with respect to some timezone, and using methods that default to different time zones, your code managed to accidentally convert between time zones :-)

Because the `Date` class is prone to such programming mistakes, it has been superseeded by a new date and time api, which you can find in the package `java.time`. Using that package, you can write:

```
var login = LocalTime.parse("08:00");
var breakDuration = Duration.between(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT, LocalTime.parse("02:00"));
var logout = LocalTime.parse("18:00");
        
var workDuration = Duration.between(login, logout).minus(breakDuration);
var workDurationString = LocalTime.MIDNIGHT.plus(workDuration).toString();
```

(if you wish to be more lenient in parsing / formatting, or use a different format, you may want to use a `DateTimeFormatter`, possibly obtained from a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`, instead)

Comment: @merton This makes much more sense. Highly appreciated! thxs